# Creating related records at the same time as parent record

Tags: data-entry

I'm currently implementing a system where one can add certain entities to a repository with the added feature that at creation time of that asset, all other related assets have to be created too.

> Eg: Add a Computer, and at the same time add it's components (CPU, Disk, Memory, ...).

Problem is the system is so flexible one could potentially end up adding a lot of entities at once. Say for example we add a Server. Suddenly we don't need to add 1 CPU but 4 and 8 modules of Memory, 4 harddisks, etc ... On top of that the harddisks also have different properties (2 SSD's and 2 7200rpm's). To make it even harder there is a possibility a "child entity" also has children (eg: a raid controller with harddisks attached to it)

From a data-entry point of view, how can I present this to the user in an understandable and easy to use way without building either a wizard with X steps where it's easy to get lost or build a form that scrolls down the page for 4 screens? Are there any proven methods for this problem interface wise?

Answer (score 3):

how about using a data-entry tree like this

http://www.csprousers.org/help/html/data_entry_tree.htm

and this

http://responsibility.motorola.com/web_help/scriba_12b_-_Remove_this_leaf.png
http://responsibility.motorola.com/web_help/Scriba_XLM_Tools_Training/Scriba_-_Material_Data_Entry_for_Complex_Products.htm

But this will again depend upon how much data you want to enter for each entity level. If each entity has its own 10-12 specific attributes, then wizard will be more easier to use since user has to spend substantial amount of time on each entity anyways.

Answer (score 2):

As there are a lot of data, it's important to minimize user's cognitive load. The data should be clearly structured in a meaningful way and manual input should be minimized (recall over remember principle).

To support those requirements, you could:

1. **Develop templates** for the typical cases.
2. To **mantain flexibility**, allow user to add or remove data fields from the form. I.e. add new HDD or remove CPU unit.
3. **Group the data** in a meaningful way. For your example it could be such groups as: `CPU & Mainboard`, `Data Storage`, etc.
4. Let user choose the values from a list, try to **minimize manual input**. Use popup dialogs for complex values. It allows to concentrate user's attention on the task.
5. Clear **indicate status** of the group: `Not filled` (data fields are empty), `Filled partly`, `Filled`.
6. Use **smart defaults**, it its possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather have a defined workflow for defining the components one after another, with the ability to pause and resume the process in between, and returning to an overview page in between.

The overview

- describes the next required step (if no steps remain, "Mark entry as complete")
- optional steps (e.g. "Add special-purpose hardware")
- may offer to return to an earlier step
- may offer to enter data in different order (e.g. when I have to ask a colleague for something, I can still enter the rest and then get back)

This gives a structured, wizard-like workflow, but avoids blocking points where a missing piece of information will halt the entire process, and also provides for system fault resiliency (system crash will not drop the entire entry, but rather leaves you at a checkpoint).

Depending on how much data is queried per component, it might even be useful to have a "skip this question and leave TODO marker" button to formalize the process of handling incomplete information (i.e. block the "complete" button until all TODOs are resolved).

As a side note: when doing data entry, I'm always happy if there is an "expert path" that allows me to run through the form quickly by memorizing information. For example, if there is a "CPU" drop down box and I know the one I want is eleventh in the list, then typing (on the Numpad) `1` `1` `Enter` should select the right one and advance in the form.